# Access web server on LAN using IP fail

Tags: ip, lan, webserver, localhost, hosts

I have a web server in my LAN with IP: `192.168.1.103`, I can only access the web server from browser in this computer through `http://localhost:8080`, I cannot access it through `192.168.1.103:8080`, nor can I access it through other computer on the LAN.

Could anyone shed some light on how to solve this?

Comment: Which Webserver are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your firewall is not blocking the port `8080`. The default por for html is `80` so maybe you've that configuration wrong. Also, can the other computers in the LAN `ping` to that IP?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is not the firewall i think, since as I said in my question I can't access the web server using ip address even on that web server computer. Other computer can ping the IP too.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your statement. I haven't had a similar scenario since the problems are most commonly when using a host name and usually the IP address always has access. Have you tried to flush your DNS and disabling your computer's firewall completely as well as your router's? And any antivirus too?

Comment: Never mind, Thanks for your help, I just solve this problem thanks to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534967/is-there-any-way-to-access-gae-dev-app-server-in-the-local-network, i forget to mention i work on GAE which is actually a jetty server inside.

Comment: I was about to suggest you check which hosts have access yo the server but I'm glad that solved your issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose perhaps you have simply bound your web server to your 127 address rather than your 192 address or the 0.0.0.0 address which allows any connections even outside your lan (though a firewall can secure it).

if you do netstat -aon  you'll see 127.0.0.1

look for your particular web server, how to bind it to the correct address.  If it showed up in netstat -aon as 0.0.0.0 then your problem should be solved. I think if it's bound to a 192 address that might work too for the rest of your LAN.